# htaccess "http://" added in url redirection issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Google webmaster reported this url `http://mywebsite.com/food-pack/http://` is accessed by some of my website users and they are getting a 404 error.

I want to redirect this 301 permanently to this url `http://mywebsite.com/food-pack/`

In my web application `food-pack` is a directory, in which I have a `.htaccess` file with following code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /food-pack/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /food-pack/$1/ [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^success/$ /food-pack/success.php [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Could anyone please tell me how I should implement that 301 redirect as `http://mywebsite.com/food-pack/http://` **->** `http://mywebsite.com/food-pack/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like :

```
# Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 /food-pack/http:// http://mywebsite.com/food-pack/
```

Comment: I have added this in main `.htaccess` file which is outside the `food-pack` directory. It's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your .htaccess like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /food-pack/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /http:/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /food-pack/? [L,NE,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^success/$ success.php [QSA]
</IfModule>
```